# Multiple where linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use multiple filter on my recordset, so I tried with following

```
var myData = ...
var fdata = myData
          .Where(x => x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.A) 
          .Where(x => x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.B)
          .Where(x => x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.C)
.ToList();
```

I want to query data if fdata is any of this MyType (A, B or C).

Comment: What's the problem? You only said what you want. I suspect it encompasses more than knowing how to use the `||` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example

```
   var fdata =  myData.Where(x => x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.A ||  x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.B ||  x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.C )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write the code like that:

```
var fdata = myData
      .Where(x => x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.A ||
       x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.B ||
       x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.C)
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

```
var myData = ...
var fdata = myData
          .Where(x => x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.A ||
           x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.B ||
           x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.C)
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myData = ...
var fdata =
    myData
        .Where(x =>
            x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.A
                || x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.B
                || x.Type == Domain.Model.MyType.C)
        .ToList();
```

You are better off doing a `.ToArray()` at the end, unless you need a list, as it is more memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `||` you can use...

```
Domain.Model.MyType[] types = new Domain.Model.MyType[] {
    Domain.Model.MyType.A, Domain.Model.MyType.B, Domain.Model.MyType.C
};
var myData = ...
var fdata = myData.Join(types, x => x.Type, y => y, (x, y) => x);
```

or...

```
Domain.Model.MyType[] types = new Domain.Model.MyType[] {
    Domain.Model.MyType.A, Domain.Model.MyType.B, Domain.Model.MyType.C
};
var myData = ...
var fdata = myData.Where(x => types.Contains(x.Type));
```

...but `||` is good solution.